# Windows Vista stops working when I am using Roxio to convert video files

Tags: windows-vista

I am using ROXIO to:

1. copy DVD file to my computer
2. trim a section of the video
3. convert the file to [WMV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video) and this is where Windows Vista gives the message that the program cannot continue.

I have followed all of the instructions from ROXIO support to clean my system and do a new install. It still does not work.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Could we have some more info on what means "It still does not work"? Error messages, screenshots etc.

Comment: Screenshot. Soulds like DEP fault. Check for a newer version of whatever program you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't -have- to use Roxio, try [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) - I use it, it's free, simple, and works well. Roxio shipped with the machines we use at work, and I did find it to be somewhat unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Ahead Nero has also a lot of tools, wave & video editor and others

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/Blockquote) is a good video editing tool

> VirtualDub is a video capture/processing utility for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows platforms (98/ME/NT4/2000/XP/Vista/7), licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL).  It lacks the editing power of a general-purpose editor such as Adobe Premiere, but is streamlined for fast linear operations over video.  It has batch-processing capabilities for processing large numbers of files and can be extended with third-party video filters.  VirtualDub is mainly geared toward processing AVI files, although it can read (not write) MPEG-1 and also handle sets of BMP images